# Is this a Beamer theme?

Tags: beamer

I found the good-looking slides

[image]

And I was wondering whether it is a beamer theme or a PowerPoint theme? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: The PDF info says 'LaTeX with beamer class', so almost certainly yes

Comment: Thank you, @JosephWright. I didn't know that I can check the PDF info. It is good to know it is a beamer theme. It seems very modern, and the hand-drawn annotations look cute. Hopefully, someone knows the exact theme.

Comment: All the possible combinations of the classic theme can be found [here](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme is called `jambrostyle`  and is available from https://github.com/ambropo/VAR-Toolbox/blob/main/beamerthemejambrostyle.sty

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{jambrostyle}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]